# Как проверить данные?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, html5, css3

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="age" value="over50" required />
```

**required** не поддерживается на iOS браузерах.
 
Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, происходила проверка на пустые поля и сообщала пользователю, на той же странице, где и форма.
Вариант с js и выводом alert сообщения не подходит. 
Как еще можно решить данную задачу?

Comment: а почему бы не проверить через js и обвести красным бордером/аутлайном/box-shadow? самое близкое к required. при желании можно и фокус на нужное поле ставить

Comment: @lexxl а возможно ли добавить текст, на месте фокуса? Типо "Вы не заполнили строку № 2 ". Выделить не получится, так как все инпуты - это type="radio"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Навскидку примерно вот так:

```css
label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px white,
              0 0 4px 4px red;
}
label:after {
  content: "Вы не заполнили строку № 2";
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" /><span>description</span>
</label>
```